# Potential energy of a pendulum from negative integral of force

Tags: forces, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, everyday-life

I seem to be having a doubt with the potential energy of a simple pendulum. If potential energery is defined as $-\int F(x)dx $ and the net force on the pendulum is $-mg\sin(\theta)$, then  wouldn't the potential energy be $-mg\cos(\theta)$? But shouldn't it be $-mgl\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: $dx$ is not equal to $d\theta$. $dx=rd\theta$

Comment: Is there an explanation as to why it's $rd\theta$?

Comment: Try the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Calculus) on polar coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the point of suspension as reference level and angle made by string with vertical as  $\theta$.

> potential energy is defined as energy of system due to gravitational force of earth  .
> `*Potential energy= displacement from reference level*`

---

it should be $-mgl\cos(\theta)$  ...........where mg us the force and displacement from reference is $l\cos(\theta)$

### for given force

W= int -F.dx

Int$-mg\sin(\theta)(rd(\theta))$

•You can check this image for how we write displacement for small curvature
https://images.app.goo.gl/qbNSbvESHVJbwQGY9

Comment: Yes, I get that this should be the answer and understand where it comes from, but I am trying to get this same result by taking the negative integral of $-mg\sin(\theta)$

Comment: The work is not the integral of force alone.  You have to multiply the force by displacement and then integrate.